# What is the File type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

initially I have something like this. As you cans see its working. But I want to replace the User with `File type` which come from typescript

```
type User = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
  };

 const myData: Record<string, User> = {
    '123-123-123': { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe' },
    '124-124-124': { firstName: 'Sarah', lastName: 'Doe' },
    '125-125-125': { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Smith' },
  };
```

After replacing I don't know what to place in the object.

```
const myData: Record<string, File> = {
        '123-123-123': { ... },
        '124-124-124': { ... },
        '125-125-125': { ... },
      };
```

I tried to place these in the object but its still giving me error

```
'123-123-123': { 
     name: 'something',
     lastModified: 123,
     webkitRelativePath: 'awef',
 },


export class FileService {
  async uploadFile(
    fileId: string,
    {
      documents,
      checkbox,
    }: { documents?: Record<string, File>; checkbox?: boolean }
  ): Promise<FileEntry> {
    const form = new FormData();

    Object.entries(documents || {}).forEach(([k, file]) =>
      form.append(k, file, file.name)
    );
    return ...
  }
}


 uploadFile('somestring',{
       documents: what to put here,
       checkbox: true,
   });
```

Input Component, This is the component that I am currently using. As you can see it is using `new FileReader()` method which I am not very clear,

So should I use the `data` from `addEventListener`  or `files` when I use that function

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
      const listener = () => {
        const files: FileList | null | undefined = inputRef.current?.files;
        if (files && files?.length > 0) {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
          reader.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
            const data = (e?.target?.result as string) || undefined;
            onChange(data);
          });
        }
      };
      inputRef.current.addEventListener('change', listener);
      return () => inputRef.current?.removeEventListener('change', listener);
    }
    return () => {
      /* */
    };
  }, [onChange]);


return (<> 
       <input
              type="file"
              accept={mime}
              multiple={false}
              placeholder="upload photo"
              ref={inputRef}
            />... 
       </>)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use the `File` type if you don't have data that matches it?

Comment: check the File type from its definition,

Comment: @Quentin Actually I have a function that accept a file `FileService. uploadFile` But I don't know what to pass in when I call the function

Comment: Not sure why you want to use `File` directly, but [here's the definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/main/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5181-L5185)

Comment: @Khant — Normally you would use a function like that with a file the user picks from a `<input type="file">` … so what do you have that you want to treat as a file but isn't one?

Comment: @Quentin I update the question. I want to know what to put in that function. 

the `files` object coming from `inputRef.current?.files` or  the `data`  that is in the `eventListener`